# revert TextFieldTableCell value

Tags: javafx-2

I used Example 13-10 TableViewSample with Enabled Cell Editing in this page:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

let's see this portion:

```
firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                            ).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );
```

In the handle method I want to do something which catch exception, and when exception occurs the cell text must be reverted to its old value.
But I can not change the text, when I call

```
((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                            ).setFirstName(t.getOldValue());
```

just changes the value of tableView data, not displayed text